# Unable to delete item from DynamoDB StringSet with boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table that contains an attribute of type StringSet. The attributes name is `allDevices`. I am trying to remove a device id from the StringSet. However, when I run the below code, it does not remove the string from the StringSet. It also does not throw any error. When attempting to remove deviceID `fakeID1` response is :

```html
{'Attributes': {'allDevices': {'fakeID1', 'fakeID2'}}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '<removed>', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Fri, 22 Feb 2019 09:04:52 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '93', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '<removed>', 'x-amz-crc32': '<removed>'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

How do I get DynamoDB to remove a string from the StringSet?

Python Code:

```html
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('sniffer-users')
try:
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'username': user,
        },
        UpdateExpression="DELETE allDevices :s",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':s': set(deviceID),
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    print(response)
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    return -9
```

Things I have tried:

- Removing `set()` from around deviceID
- Change `DELETE` to `REMOVE`
- Banging my head against a wall, begging & pleading
- Explicitly setting `fakeID1` to make it read `':s': set('fakeID1'),`
- Using the syntax `':s': {'SS': [oldDeviceID]},`
- Quadruple checking that `allDevices` is the same in code as on DDB
- Adding something to `allDevices` - this works flawlessly
- Changing runtime from Python 3.7 to Python 2.7

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make a minor modification to your ExpressionAttributeValues. To convert a single string into a set, you must first make it a list.

```
ExpressionAttributeValues={
    ':s': set([deviceID]),
}
```

Notice the difference below between putting your variable inside [] to make it list and not doing so.

```
>>> deviceID = "WB529"
>>> set(deviceID)
set(['9', '2', 'B', '5', 'W'])
>>> set([deviceID])
set(['WB529'])
```

This delete operation will indicate it is successful and return "updated" attributes even if **no changes** have been made. I have some really similar code; it is impossible to tell from the response if you removed an element from the stringset or if it was never there to begin with.

I haven't tried it, but I believe that adding a ConditionExpression will give you that feedback (the operation will either succeed or will throw an exception).